# How to transform time data in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a list and I want to convert each item's `duration` property from seconds to minutes ("MM:SS").

This is my actual rendering:

[image]

And this is my code:

**Template**:

```html
<div *ngIf="lesson$ | async as lesson">
  <div
    class="flex items-center justify-between top-margin"
    *ngFor="let lessonData of lesson.lessons"
  >
    <div class="flex items-center">
      <img src="assets/images/sliders/lock.svg" class="mr-right" alt="" />
      <p class="text-sm font-normal text-darkgray course-box-title">
        {{ lessonData.title }}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text-sm font-normal text-regulargray">
        {{ lessonData.duration }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component**:

```js
export class LessonCardComponent {
  public lesson$: Observable<ICourse> = this._store.select(selectSelectedCourse);

  constructor(private readonly _store: Store<AppState>, public dialog: MatDialog) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Among so many possibilities, you can create a pipe to transform your data:

```js
function withLeadingZeroes(value: number): string {
  const integer = Math.floor(value);
  return `0${integer}`.slice(-2);
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'appSecondsToMinutes' // choose your name, it's just a random name
})
export class SecondsToMinutesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(seconds: number): string {
    const minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    return [minutes, seconds % 60].map(withLeadingZeroes).join(':');
  }
}
```

Usage:

```html
{{ lessonData.duration | appSecondsToMinutes }}
```

PS: Don't forget to add the `@Pipe` to the `NgModule`'s declarations.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwkvix)

Answer (score 1):

If your `lessonData.duration` is in milliseconds, you can use the built-in pipe [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
{{ lessonData.duration | date: 'mm:ss' }}
```